# Can't deploy go lang app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here is how my files are organized before I zip the file.

```
├── app
│   ├── main.go
│   ├── Procfile
│   ├── Buildfile
│   ├── build.sh
```

Buildfile

```
make: ./build.sh
```

build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install dependencies.
go get ./...

# Build app
go build ./ -o bin/application
```

Procfile

```
web: bin/application
```

The error I get

> [Instance: i-03f3c230e7b575431] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... inflating: /var/app/staging/app/main.go Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain a Buildfile, Procfile or an executable. Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain a Buildfile, Procfile or an executable. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

More error logs

```
Application update failed at 2018-10-02T01:33:44Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed.

Executing: /usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
Archive: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
creating: /var/app/staging/app/
inflating: /var/app/staging/app/Buildfile
inflating: /var/app/staging/app/build.sh
inflating: /var/app/staging/app/Procfile
inflating: /var/app/staging/app/main.go
Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain a Buildfile, Procfile or an executable.
Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain a Buildfile, Procfile or an executable.
Incorrect application version ".01" (deployment 29). Expected version ".01" (deployment 18).
```

My main.go file has third-party packages. I'm using

```
port := os.Getenv("PORT")
if port == "" {
    port = "5000"
    log.Println("[-] No PORT environment variable detected. Setting to ", port)
}
```

like the docs say in the example app. It compiles and runes locally no problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in your error message:

Unable to launch application as the source bundle does not contain a Buildfile, Procfile or an executable.

Your Procfile, Buildfile and build.sh should be in the root of the project, like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── main.go
│   Procfile
│   Buildfile
│   build.sh
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference to OPs structure? is the Procfile, Buildfile and build.sh all on the same level as the app folder or inside? If it is on the same level does the go.mod, go.sum and application.go go in the app folder or same as the Procfile etc?