# Deploy Go to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Summary:

I am trying to deploy a go app on AWS elastic beanstalk, but I always get:

```
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797145 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Check Procfile For Golang Application]. Stop running the command. Error: no application binary from source
```

or

```
2023/11/01 17:31:03.667171 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Golang Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: build application failed on command ./build.sh with error: startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xeu make.service" for details.
```

Depending on the configuration that I am trying.
I created a [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/ali-g/go-elastic-beanstalk) with a basic example that can reproduce this issue. It also includes the zip that is used to deploy the code. I have tried cloning the [demo repo](https://github.com/mrichman/elastic-beanstalk-go-demo) and working from there. I have found that from this repo even just adding a go.mod and go.sum already makes the deployment fail and so does simply updating the application.go file to look like this:

```
package main

// required packages
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
)


func serveApplication() {
    corsConfig := cors.Config {
        AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{"Origin", "Content-Type", "Authorization"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    }

    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(cors.New(corsConfig))
    router.StaticFile("/", "./public/index.html")
    router.Run(":5000")
    fmt.Println("Server running on port 5000")
}

func main() {
    // start the server
    serveApplication()

}
```

### Is there something that I am not considering that is breaking the build?

I am trying to deploy a go app to an AWS elastic beanstalk environment but I get the following messages in the eb-enginge.log:

```
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797089 [INFO] checking Buildfile...
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797094 [INFO] no Buildfile found, checking application.go file
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797100 [INFO] no application.go file
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797103 [INFO] Executing instruction: Check Procfile For Golang Application
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797127 [INFO] no Procfile found, checking binary application
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797132 [INFO] no application binary found in bin directory from source
2023/10/31 14:01:25.797145 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Check Procfile For Golang Application]. Stop running the command. Error: no application binary from source
```

However, I have a Buildfile, application.go, Procfile and build.sh. When I unzip the zip that I upload I see the directory structure to be this:

```
.ebextensions/-> directory with config files
portal/-> directory with application code and application.go
.env -> env file
Buildfile
Procfile
build.sh
go.mod
go.sum
application -> generated application binary
```

My Buildfile looks like this:

```
make: ./build.sh
```

My Procfile like this:

```
web: application
```

My build.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install dependencies.
go get ./...

# Build app
go build -o application portal/application.go
```

I have tried with a project structure like this:

```
application.go
(with and without application binary in root directory)
build.sh
Buildfile
Procfile
```

Also I have tried to generate the binary in a bin subdirectory to achieve a structure like this:

```
.ebextensions/-> directory with config files
portal/-> directory with application code and application.go
.env -> env file
Buildfile
Procfile
build.sh
go.mod
go.sum
bin/application -> generated application binary
```

No matter what I do I get the error that there is no binary. I don't understand what is wrong according to AWS docs I need to provision either 1. application.go at root of zip (which I tried) or 2. bundle with a binary called application at root or in bin directory (which I also tried). Is there anything I am missing? I tried setting up the directory structure like in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600975/cant-deploy-go-lang-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk). I have also tried zipping from inside the folder with this command:

```
zip dist.zip .ebextenstions Buildfile Procfile build.sh application
```

When I deploy that I get the following error:

```
2023/10/31 14:58:28.659021 [INFO] Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xeu make.service" for details.

2023/10/31 14:58:28.659054 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Golang Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: build application failed on command ./build.sh with error: startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xeu make.service" for details.
```

So then I updated Procfile

```
make: chmod +x build.sh; ./build.sh
```

Which then gives me the error:

```
2023/10/31 15:02:33.422372 [INFO] Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xeu make.service" for details.

2023/10/31 15:02:33.422414 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Golang Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: build application failed on command chmod +x build.sh; ./build.sh with error: startProcess Failure: starting process "make" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start make.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for make.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status make.service" and "journalctl -xeu make.service" for details.
```

I created a [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/ali-g/go-elastic-beanstalk) with a minimum example that can reproduce this issue. It also includes the zip that is used to deploy the code

NOTE: I have successfully deployed the go app in a docker container on elastic beanstalk but because I am trying to configure https for a single instance and as far as I could find out (and from trying) using ebextensions doesn't really work if you run a docker image by uploading a Dockerrun.aws.json (I then read that you should just zip the entire directory with the ebextensions directory and Dockerrunaws.json but that did not work either) so now I am trying to follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-go.html) to configure my go app with https

Comment: Instead of deploying app via zip... Have you tried using dockerfile ?

Comment: yeah, I have deployed a go app in a docker container without a problem, but I am trying to configure https on a single instance and I could not configure the server successfully with the ebextensions files when running in a docker container. Therefore I am now trying to deploy the go app directly and configure https on the single instance following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-go.html